# Styles loading after angular application loads with CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just started porting my existing angular application to use the cli now that it has been released. However I noticed the styles are loading after my application starts loading. During application loading I display a loading gif which I center in the page. What is happening now is that it appears in the top left of the page for a split second then the styles are loaded centering the the gif then loads the application.

Is there any way to mimic the behavior as if I had a link tag at the top of my html page loading the css? Right now it bundles my styles in a js file and is loaded at the bottom of the body tag causing the delay.

My .angular-cli.json is below:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "program-quick-view-cli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "assets/styles/main.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "assets/js/pdfmake.min.js",
        "assets/js/Treant.js",
        "assets/js/vfs_fonts.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest injecting/embedding just the styles for your loading page directly in your index.html, so you don't get FOUC at any point of the loading process. In fact, I even embed my loading graphic in the CSS so that doesn't need the additional request.

Comment: @SteveG. sorry what does FOUC mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a super snappy load of your "loading page", I would suggest injecting/embedding just the styles for your loading page directly in your index.html, so you don't get [FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) at any point of the loading process. In fact, you can even embed your loading graphic in the CSS so that doesn't need the additional request.

For example (using an SVG):

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <style>
        @keyframes knock-their-socks-off {
            /*  ... */
        }

        .cool-loader {
            /*  ... */
            animation: knock-their-socks-off 10s infinite;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...");
            /*  ... */
        }
    </style>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <app-root>
        <div class="cool-loader"></div>
    </app-root>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rest-of-site.css" ...>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

If you're using a GIF, you can Base64 encode it for embedding. Just be wary that the larger the file, the more it will inflate your index.html.

Comment: is that really the only workaround? I don't have a problem with it but seems silly to me that I have to put my styles in my index html

Comment: Well, it's more of a "personal choice" for you.  Typically in Web optimization, the requests are [generally] the "expensive part" of a Web page load.  Using this technique, you're reducing your requests (by one with the embed) and eliminating the lag that may be encountered by remote requests e.g. slower connections. (Since it's your loading page, I'm assuming you want it to be fast and not block other items being loaded.)  You could then re-use this loading class in other places of your application as well.